# Combine Windows in Win-7 style

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-installer, custom-action

Is it possible to combine two dialogs on taskbar in windows 7 fashion, if one of them is an unmanaged window.

For example - I have a setup project and CustomActions library written on managed code. I'm opening a form in my CustomInstaller class. I know it's sounds crazy, but I suppose there is a way to combine them together on the taskbar. I don't like the way they look on taskbar right now - like two different apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need the same Application ID. You can set it with an API call. The [Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) is the easiest way to do it from C#.